# I am misunderstood, what am I?

Tags: riddle

> I am united, and
>
> I am old, like a wine
>
> I am popular now, east to west, but
>
> I am misunderstood
>
> I am known in several forms/names, but
>
> I am inclusive of many of them
>
> I am given a day, but
>
> I am good for a life time
>
> I am present now, and
>
> I am alive now
>
> I am here to help you, so that
>
> I am to be attained by you

Since no one has answered it, I am adding couple of hints

> I am employed in many fields now
>
> I am of Sanskrit origin

What am I?

Comment: Accepts the downvotes. But prey tell me the reason. :)

Comment: I've downvoted this question because I think it follows a pattern that doesn't lend itself very well to high-interest riddles - primarily, it relies solely on recognizing an object by a few aspects of it that have been alluded to in individual lines. Riddles of this type tend to be straightforward to solve by recognition and prior knowledge alone, rather than pushing the reader for metaphorical reasoning.

Comment: @Deusovi Overload :), I think you are referring to [this](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5160/what-should-we-do-about-riddles-that-are-pure-trivia), correct?

Comment: Yes: riddles usually need to have some sort of metaphor or wordplay to be good. Riddles that just list characteristics of an object or person are boring, and maybe not even riddles at all!

Comment: I wonder how likely is that the answer will be lost in translation.

Comment: @Mr Pie ..How about my answer ...any bounties for me  :)

https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/40469/22890

Comment: @AmruthA the "east to west" part in RobotZebra's answer, I liked better than that part in yours. Sorry about that! However, if you feel like you deserve a tick on one of your answers, just lemme know, I will take a look, and perhaps you'll get a bounty ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer is

> Yoga(asanas)

because

I am united, and

> yoga means "to add", "to join", "to unite", or "to attach" in its most common literal sense.

I am old, like a wine

> Yoga is an incredible gift of India's ancient tradition. This tradition is about 5000 years old and yes its getting better with time as wine.

I am popular now, east to west, but

> Yeah, Its very much popular in world.

I am misunderstood

> There have been incorrect beliefs about yoga

I am known in several forms/names, but

> So many names of yoga.

I am given a day,

> 21 June international yoga day.

I am good for a life time

> Good to do it everyday.

I am present now.

> Yoga is still present.

I am alive now

> Yoga is alive in many forms.

I am here to help you, so that

> Yoga is always available to  help us to solve our health issues and to keep our body fit.

I am to be attained by you

> Yoga is always there be attained by you, you can do it whenever you want.

I am of Sanskrit origin

> Yoga Sanskrit origin

Comment: You got it. Yoga is the answer. If you can explain the wine part and the 2 lines about attaining, I can accept your answer.

Comment: @KrishnaBhadra I have just added lines you wanted check it.

Comment: "Yoga" is the target as well as the means. That is, Yoga is a set of actions devised to attain the union, which is also called Yoga. So yoga (the set of todo's) is here to help you so that you can attain Yoga (the union).

Comment: Also, once in yoga (union), you are always in the present, alive to every moment.

Answer (score 16):

Answer

> The Sun

I am united, and

> The Sun is large a collection of gas

I am old, like a wine

> The Sun is incredibly old, older than Earth to say the least.

I am popular now, east to west, but

> The Sun is recognised as rising in the east and setting in the west

I am misunderstood

> There have been many incorrect beliefs about the Sun (e.g. that it orbits Earth)

I am known in several forms/names, but

> It is studied, worshipped, revered, hated, and recognised by many names (Sol, The Sun etc.)

I am inclusive of many of them

> It can be said that most of these names beliefs have an element of truth

I am given a day, but

> the day Sunday was named after it in English

I am good for a life time

> Everyone who has ever been has lived and died in the presence of the Sun

I am present now, and

> The Sun is still with us

I am alive now

> The Sun has not died just yet

I am here to help you, so that

> Gives us light, heat

I am to be attained by you

> We absorb the light and heat in many, many forms. We all dream of one day catching the Sun.

Comment: The "day" is also referred to as when the sun is visible.

Comment: "Other names" could also be any of the [sun gods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_solar_deities), such as Ra [Egyptian] or Helios [Greek]

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE!

Comment: @DavidStarkey Great point - although I said "worshipped" I didn't actually consider specific Sun Deities. In that sense the Sun can also be said to unite all sorts of beliefs and Religions. 

Although to my knowledge the Sun wasn't formed with Sanskrit so my answer might not be the intended solution. I've been enjoying the response this solution has gotten however!

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος Thanks! I've been lurking for a short while and thought I'd give it a shot.

Answer (score 6):

> Latin

I am united, and

> Used by the Roman empire (among others)

I am old, like a wine

> Very old language (talking BC here)

I am popular now, east to west, but

> Many modern languages have Latin roots

I am misunderstood

> Few understand Latin today, (possibly even confusion with Latino?)

I am known in several forms/names, but

> [Old](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin#Old_Latin), [Classical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin#Classical_Latin), [Vulgar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin#Vulgar_Latin), [Medieval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin#Medieval_Latin), [Renaissance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin#Renaissance_Latin), the list goes on.

I am inclusive of many of them

> Despite the form, it's still Latin

I am given a day, but

> Columbus Day celebrates discovery of Latin America

I am good for a life time

> It's been used far longer than human lifetimes.

I am present now, and

> Still used in different settings (Higher education being the first that comes to mind)

I am alive now

> Languages used today still have Latin letters (English, for example)

I am here to help you, so that

> Knowing Latin can help in understanding other languages

I am to be attained by you

> [Latin honors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_honors) (cum laude, magna cum laude, summa cum laude)

Comment: Nice try, but not the answer I had in mind. Thanks for attempting :)

Answer (score 5):

Is the answer:

> God?

*I am united, and*

> There are many gods in the world, but they all are same.

*I am old, like a wine*

> The concept of God has existed for a long time.

*I am popular now, east to west, but*

> Gods are popular everywhere in the world.

*I am misunderstood*

> Some people misunderstand god, and use it as a weapon.

*I am known in several, but*

> There are many names of god.

*I am inclusive of many of them*

> All gods are same.

*I am given a day, but*

> Pray to god once a day.

*I am good for a life time*

> God will take care of us entire life.

*I am present now, and

I am alive now

I am here to help you, so that

I am to be attained by you*

> This what god does help us when we are in trouble.

Comment: Well, nice answer and good effort.  But not the correct answer. Sorry. See the language tag also.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra which language ?English..

Comment: Amruth A, I will disclose the language if no one has answered this question after some time. Just waiting. You can solve this without knowing the language, and the meaning of the word is easily googleable.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra 
 
is it like python (programming language ) and you put tag for it??

Answer (score 3):

Solution:

> Esperanto

I am united

> The World Esperanto Association has members in 120[10] countries

I am old

> Created by L. L. Zamenhof in 1887

I am popular now

> Up to 2,000,000 people worldwide

I am given a day

> Zamenhof Day, also called Esperanto Day, is celebrated on 15 December, the birthday of Esperanto creator L. L. Zamenhof.

Comment: other points???

Comment: I never even heard about this language. I think the language tag is causing confusion. I will remove it, as it is not necessary to find the answer. It is just that knowing the language is helpful for getting one of the hints.

Comment: never heard of Esperanto? :O  hahah is supose to be the *global language*

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> Love?

I am united, and

> Love unites people

I am old, like a wine

> A relationship gets better the longer it lasts

I am popular now, east to west, but

> Western countries now accept same sex relationships, whereas eastern countries more and more accept marriage based on love.

I am misunderstood

> To be honest, almost nobody gets it

I am known in several forms/names, but

> Expressed through symbols, actions, ...

I am inclusive of many of them *edit* probs @David Starkey

> Love consists on many of these gestures

I am given a day, but

> Valentines day

I am good for a life time

> Love can last a life time

I am present now, and

> Love is can be found anywhere, anytime

I am alive now

> Same as above

I am here to help you, so that

> Makes live a whole lot better

I am to be attained by you

> You won't find love without trying

Comment: "I am known in several forms/names, but I am inclusive of many of them"  For your answer, many of the forms combined make up a clearer picture of the suggested answer.

Comment: Ahhhh that's what it meant :) I wasn't able to translate it

Comment: Sorry not the answer I had in mind. I like some of your descriptions, especially the 'misunderstood' line. But the east to west line feels a bit of stretch though. Thanks for attempting. :)

Answer (score 2):

I am

> Europe, especially in the political sense of EU

I am united

> European union

I am old, like a wine

> One of the older civilized continents, also the place where wine became popular

I am popular now, east to west, but

> Still popular enough for most countries in the EU to want to stay in it, and for others like Turkey to want to join

I am misunderstood

> The political beliefs of citizens about the European union are not always correct

I am known in several forms/names, but 
I am inclusive of many of them

> Europe is a geographical, political, financial and historical entity, also the name of a mythological figure. On the political level alone, there are several things which somehow represent Europe - the EU, the Schengen area, etc.

I am given a day, but 
I am good for a life time

> There have always been people who predicted that the union will fall apart soon, but it has been around for a longish generation now

I am present now, and 
I am alive now

> It still exists

I am here to help you, so that 
I am to be attained by you

> The idea behind the union is to help its citizens. But for it to work, they have to start identifying as citizens of the EU to some extent. Without that attitude, it cannot be attained.

Comment: <cough> Brexit </cough>

Comment: I am amazed at the intelligence around here. Brilliant answer. Sadly, not the one I had in mind. The description for "I am given a day" is bit of a stretch though. Thanks for attempting :)

Answer (score 2):

> The United States

I am united, and

> The *United* States

I am old, like a wine

> The United States is over 200 years old.

I am popular now, east to west, but

> The United States is quite large for a country, well known, and stretches from its east coast to west coast.

I am misunderstood

> It is a commonly held belief that much of the rest of the world dislikes the United States despite many Americans being perfectly decent people.

I am known in several forms/names, but:

> There are several names to refer to it: United States, United States of America, America, The States, U.S., U.S.A., U.S. of A.

I am inclusive of many of them:

> Historically, the United States was a very inclusive place. Additionally, many of the previous names are well accepted.

I am given a day, but
I am good for a life time

> The United States revolution barely established the United States as a country (hence "given a day" to refer to a short amount of time). But, it was later established that the United States is definetly a country (hence "good for a life time")

I am present now, and
I am alive now

> The United States definitely exists and is "alive" in a metaphorical sense.

I am here to help you so that,
I am to be attained by you

> There is a common narrative in the United States about it being a "world policeman" who is there to fix other parts of the world. If we take the words "United States" to be a representation of democracy (not to imply other democracies don't exist -- but, the United States was arguably the first and was a model for many others), then the "help" offered by the United States should help establish democracy (hence it can be "attained") in other parts of the world.

Answer (score -1):

Answer

> Homosexuality

I am united, and

> Brings people together, who in the past would not have united

I am old, like a wine

> Been around for a long time (although not accepted by many until recently)

I am popular now, east to west, but

> It is beginning to become more accepted across the world

I am known in several names/forms

> There are many names given to the people who are part of it.

Comment: What about the rest of the lines?

Comment: Sorry, not the answer. Thanks for attempting though. :)

Comment: Wine has been accepted by many for a long time!